# Python & Pandas: Structuring lambda argument

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script in Python and Pandas that uses lambda statements to write pre-formatted comments in a csv column based on the numerical grade assigned to each row. While I'm able to do this for a number of series, I'm having difficulty with one case.

Here the is structure of the csv:

[image]

Here is the working code to write a new column `composition_comment`. (I'm sure there's a way to express this more concisely, but I'm still learning Python and Pandas.)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('stack.csv')
composition_score_value = 40  #calculated by another process

composition_comment_a_level = "Good work." # For scores falling between 100 and 90 percent of composition_score_value.
composition_comment_b_level = "Satisfactory work." # For scores between 89 and 80.
composition_comment_c_level = "Improvement needed." # For scores between 79 and 70.
composition_comment_d_level = "Unsatisfactory work." # For scores below 69.

df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(lambda element: composition_comment_a_level if element <= (composition_score_value * 1) else element >= (composition_score_value *.90))
df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(lambda element: composition_comment_b_level if element <= (composition_score_value *.899) else element >= (composition_score_value *.80))
df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(lambda element: composition_comment_c_level if element <= (composition_score_value *.799) else element >= (composition_score_value *.70))
df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(lambda element: composition_comment_d_level if element <= (composition_score_value *.699) else element >= (composition_score_value *.001))

df 

df.to_csv('stack.csv', index=False)
```

The expected output is:

[image]

But the actual output is:

[image]

Any ideas on why the `True` values being written, and why the final row processes properly? Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many of the other options show how to improve the `apply` operation, I would suggest using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['composition_comment'] = pd.cut(
    df['composition_score'] / composition_score_value,  # Divide to get percent
    bins=[0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, np.inf],                    # Set Bounds
    labels=[composition_comment_d_level,                # Set Labels
            composition_comment_c_level,
            composition_comment_b_level,
            composition_comment_a_level],
    right=False                                         # Set Lower bound inclusive
)
```

`df`:

```
   composition_score   composition_comment
0                 40            Good work.
1                 35    Satisfactory work.
2                 31   Improvement needed.
3                 27  Unsatisfactory work.
```

*Setting `right=False` makes the lowerbound inclusive meaning the bins are:

```
[0.0, 0.7)  # 0.0 (inclusive) up to 0.7 (not inclusive)
[0.7, 0.8)  # 0.7 (inclusive) up to 0.8 (not inclusive)
[0.8, 0.9)  # 0.8 (inclusive) up to 0.9 (not inclusive)
[0.9, inf)  # 0.9 (inclusive) up to infinity
```

Notes:

1. `inf` could be modified if there was a set upper bound. `1` will *not* work as the upper bound with `right=False` since 1 is not strictly less than 1.
2. `np.NINF` could be used instead of the lower bound if values less than 0 are expected

---

The primary benefit is that there is a categorical which is returned. Meaning that operations like `sort_values` will sort, not alphabetically, but rather by category.

```
['Unsatisfactory work.' < 'Improvement needed.' < 'Satisfactory work.' < 'Good work.']
```

```
df = df.sort_values('composition_comment')
```

`df`:

```
   composition_score   composition_comment
3                 27  Unsatisfactory work.
2                 31   Improvement needed.
1                 35    Satisfactory work.
0                 40            Good work.
```

---

Program Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'composition_score': [40, 35, 31, 27]})
composition_score_value = 40  # calculated by another process

# For scores falling between 100 and 90 percent of composition_score_value.
composition_comment_a_level = "Good work."
# For scores between 89 and 80.
composition_comment_b_level = "Satisfactory work."
# For scores between 79 and 70.
composition_comment_c_level = "Improvement needed."
# For Scores below 70
composition_comment_d_level = "Unsatisfactory work."
```

Answer (score 1):

`else` returns nothing in the lambda functions, so it only returns True. I suggest combining them in a single function, while also inverting the order:

```
composition_score_value = 40  #calculated by another process

def return_level(element):
    if element <= (composition_score_value *.699):
        return "Unsatisfactory work." # For scores below 69.
    elif element <= (composition_score_value *.799):
        return "Improvement needed." # For scores between 79 and 70.
    elif element <= (composition_score_value *.899):
        return "Satisfactory work." # For scores between 89 and 80.
    elif element <= (composition_score_value * 1):
        return "Good work." # For scores falling between 100 and 90 percent of composition_score_value.
    else:
        return None

df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(return_level)
```

Result:

|  | composition_score | composition_comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40 | Good work. |
| 1 | 35 | Satisfactory work. |
| 2 | 31 | Improvement needed. |
| 3 | 27 | Unsatisfactory work. |

Comment: Success! Assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Great answer to the OP question. @Daniel Hutchinson, you may give my answer a look if you're interested in a more scalable solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

It overwrites what you have done in the above lines of codes. When it sees a value that satisfies `element <= (composition_score_value *.699)` it returns composition_comment_d_level. If value doesn't satisfy that, then it returns `element >= (composition_score_value *.001)`, which is essentially a boolean value, True or False.

This one should work:

```py
def composition_comment(element):
    composition_score_value = 40
    if element <= (composition_score_value *.699) :
        return "Unsatisfactory work."  
    elif element <= (composition_score_value *.799):
        return "Improvement needed."
    elif  element <= (composition_score_value *.899):
        return "Satisfactory work."
    elif element <= (composition_score_value * 1):
        return "Good work."
    else:
        return None

df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(composition_comment)
df
```

Comment: You need to reverse either the order of the comparison, or their directions. As it stands, any score less than `composition_score_value` will result in `"Good work."`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.cut()` to perform the mapping, and this scales much better than having to explicitly write out each condition in an `if-else` statement:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'composition_score': [40, 35, 31, 27]})
composition_score_value = 40

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 70), (70,80), (80,90), (90,100)])
labels = ['Unsatisfactory work.','Improvement needed.','Satisfactory work.','Good work.']
d = dict(zip(bins,labels))
x = pd.cut(df['composition_score']/composition_score_value*100, bins, right=False).map(d)
```

Yields:

```
0              Good work.
1      Satisfactory work.
2     Improvement needed.
3    Unsatisfactory work.
Name: composition_score, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['Unsatisfactory work.' < 'Improvement needed.' < 'Satisfactory work.' < 'Good work.']
```

Comment: I think the bins should be `[(0, 70), (70,80), (80,90), (90,100)]`, and then set `right = False`.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way using Numpy, instead of `if/elif` usage:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [ (df['composition_score']>90,
               (df['composition_score']>80) & (df['composition_score']<90),
               (df['composition_score']>70) & (df['composition_score']<80),
               (df['composition_score']<70
                      ]

choices = ['Great','Not Bad','Poor','very ugly']


df['composition_comment'] = np.select(conditions , choices , default='')
```

**Note**: `default=''` rapresents the default value when no conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

First, a style comment: you should be using more carriage returns, and your variable names are rather long (including both "score" and "value" in a name is a bit redundant). I believe the following will still work, and not require side scrolling:

```
df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(
    lambda element: comp_comment_a if element <= (comp_score * 1) 
        else element >= (comp_score *.90))
```

As for what's going on, the above code tells Python that you want `comp_comment_a` if `element` is less than or equal to `comp_score * 1`, otherwise you want the value of `element >= (comp_score *.90)`. And `element >= (comp_score *.90)` is a boolean. I'm not entirely clear on what your intended result is, but based on my guess as to what you want, you should have `and` rather than `else`. Your code can be made much cleaner, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('stack.csv')
comp_score = 40  #calculated by another process

comp_comments = ["Good work.", "Satisfactory work.", "Improvement needed.", 
    "Unsatisfactory work."]

def score_to_comment(score):
    if score > comp_score:
        #it's not clear what you want to do in this case
        #but this follows your original code
        return None
    if score >= comp_score * .9:
        return comp_comments[0]
    if score >= comp_score * .8:
       return comp_comments[1]
    if score >= comp_score * .7:
       return comp_comments[2]
    return comp_comments[3]

df['composition_comment'] = df['composition_score'].apply(score_to_comment)

df.to_csv('stack.csv', index=False)
```